# How to do code coverage for setter methods in junit

Tags: junit, mockito

I am new to junit & mockito.

Actual Method:

```
public void processRecords(ConsumerRecord<String, LocationMessagePayload> record) {
    try {
        MDC.put("transaction-id", record.value().getHeader().getTransactionId());
        billerInvokeService.processMessage(record.value());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LocationSyncResponse response = getLocationSyncResponseForErrorCode(BLC_P);
        response.setCause(e.getMessage);
        response.setErrorCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        FalloutDTO falloutDTO = falloutMapper.prpareFalloutMessage(response, record.value());
        billerInvokeService.sendMessage(record.value().getBody().getCurrentState().getLocation().getServiceLocationId().toString(), falloutDTO);
    }
}
```

Test Case:

```
@Test
void processRecordsTest_Exception() {
    Header header = new Header();
    header.setTransactionId("transactionId");
    ConsumerRecord<String, LocationMessagePayload> record = new ConsumerRecord<>("","");
    when(billerInvokeService.processMessage(locationMessagePayload)).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());
    when(locationMessagePayload.getHeader()).thenReturn(header);
    
    FalloutDTO falloutDTO = new FalloutDTO();
    falloutDTO.setCause("AP Test");
    falloutDTO.setSource("InvokeTest);
    
    when(falloutMapper.prpareFalloutMessage(any(LocationSyncResponse.class), eq(locationMessagePayload))).thenReturn(falloutDTO);
    
    Location location = mock(Location.class);
    when(location.getServiceLocationId()).thenReturn(123L):
    State currentState = mock(State.class);
    when(currentState.getLocation()).thenReturn(location);
    Body body = mock(Body.class);
    when(body.getCurrentState()).thenReturn(currentState);
    when(locationMessagePayload.getBody()).thenReturn(body);
    
    billerConsumer.processRecords(record);
    verify(billerInvokeService, times(1)).sendMessage(record.value().getBody().getCurrentState().getLocation().getServiceLocationId().toString(), falloutDTO);
}
```

Problem: Below two lines are not covered under code coverage

```
response.setCause(e.getMessage);
response.setErrorCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
```

Help me to resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That should work. Have you verified with a debugger that the exception is thrown and your catch block is being executed?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the method `processMessage` is forced to throw an exception with this line of code:

```
when(billerInvokeService.processMessage(locationMessagePayload)).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());
```

I suggest removing this `thenThrow` statement and simulating exception throwing with `try/catch` block.

```
    @Test
    void processRecordsTest_Exception() {
        // set up test data
        Header header = new Header();
        header.setTransactionId("transactionId");
        ConsumerRecord<String, LocationMessagePayload> record = new ConsumerRecord<>("","");

        // set up mock objects
        LocationMessagePayload locationMessagePayload = mock(LocationMessagePayload.class);
        when(billerInvokeService.processMessage(locationMessagePayload)).thenReturn(null);
        when(locationMessagePayload.getHeader()).thenReturn(header);

        // set up fallout mapper mock
        FalloutDTO falloutDTO = new FalloutDTO();
        falloutDTO.setCause("AP Test");
        falloutDTO.setSource("InvokeTest");
        when(falloutMapper.prpareFalloutMessage(any(LocationSyncResponse.class), eq(locationMessagePayload))).thenReturn(falloutDTO);

        // set up location and state mock objects
        Location location = mock(Location.class);
        when(location.getServiceLocationId()).thenReturn(123L);
        State currentState = mock(State.class);
        when(currentState.getLocation()).thenReturn(location);
        Body body = mock(Body.class);
        when(body.getCurrentState()).thenReturn(currentState);
        when(locationMessagePayload.getBody()).thenReturn(body);

        try {
            billerConsumer.processRecords(record);
            fail("Expected an exception to be thrown");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            verify(billerInvokeService, times(1)).sendMessage(record.value().getBody().getCurrentState().getLocation().getServiceLocationId().toString(), falloutDTO);

            LocationSyncResponse response = getLocationSyncResponseForErrorCode(BLC_P);
            response.setCause(e.getMessage());
            response.setErrorCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
            FalloutDTO expectedFalloutDTO = falloutMapper.prpareFalloutMessage(response, locationMessagePayload);
            assertEquals(expectedFalloutDTO, falloutDTO);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But the test case is failing. it is not executing lines which are in catch clause.